# Unable to Access Protected API Endpoint After Successful Login in Node.js Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have developed registration and login APIs using Express, Mongoose, and Node.js. I am testing these APIs using Postman.

The registration and login APIs are working correctly, and the tokens are being saved in cookies and headers upon successful login. However, I am facing an issue when trying to access a protected API endpoint, specifically the "create product" API endpoint. This endpoint should only be accessible to authenticated users.

I have verified that the token is being returned in the response headers and cookies upon successful login, so I'm not sure why it is not being sent automatically in subsequent requests.

**Code for the login API endpoint**

> ```
> app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
>
>     const { email, password } = request.body
>     const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password")
>
>    if (!user) {
>        return (next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid credentials1.', 401)))
>    }
>
>    Compare the provided password with the stored password
>    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
>    if (!passwordMatch) {
>        return (next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid credentials2.', 401)))
>    }
>
>    const token = user.getJWTToken()
>
>    const options = {
>    expires: new Date(
>    Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE_DATE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
>    httpOnly: true
>    }
>
>    response.status(statusCode).cookie('token',token,options).json({
>       sucess:true,
>       message: message,
>       user,
>       token,
>    })
> });
> ```

**Middleware to verify login status**

> ```
> const verifyLogin = (req, res, next) => {
>
>     //Retrieving the cookie
>     const { token } = request.cookies
>
>     console.log(request)
>
>     if (!token) {
>         return next(new ErrorHandler("Login to access. ", 401))
>     }
>
>     const decodedData = jwtToken.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
>     request.user = await User.findById(decodedData.userId)
>     next()
> };
> ```

When testing the APIs using Postman, I registered a user successfully and received a token in the response headers and cookies. Then, I logged in with the registered user and obtained a new token, again saved in headers and cookies.

However, when I tried to access the protected "create product" API endpoint using a new request in Postman, I received an error message stating "Login to access this resource." It seems that the token is not being automatically sent in subsequent requests.

I expected the token to be automatically included in the request headers or cookies after successful login, allowing me to access the protected API endpoints without any issues.

I have already verified that the tokens are being saved correctly in the login and registration APIs, and they are returned in the response headers and cookies. However, the token is not automatically sent in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
const verifyLogin = (req, res, next) => {

    //Retrieving the cookie
    const { token } = request.cookies

    console.log(request)

    if (!token) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Login to access. ", 401))
    }

    const decodedData = jwtToken.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
    request.user = await User.findById(decodedData.userId)
    next()
};
```

In the above middleware you should change
`const {token} = req.cookies` instead of `const {token} = request.cookies` because the argument of the middleware is written as req